# Can I a new light fixture to existing recessed lighting?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I recently converted a 400 sq/ft area of our basement to a hang out area for our kids.  We had recessed lighting put in however we noticed that some areas (the corners in particular) were not well lit.  I'd like to run a line from the last recessed light to the center of the ceiling and add track lighting that can help light up the corners of the room.

Can I add a line for regular lighting to an existing recessed light?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional lighting fixture from *any* of the existing ones so long as the total load doesn't trip the breaker. Note - unless you're using some old tech, *very* high load lighting, you're not going to come anywhere *close* to overloading a 15a lighting circuit. Of course, if there are outlets on the circuit and you plug in a space heater, you might, but that's a different story.

Make sure that your wiring runs to a properly mounted ceiling box for the wiring for your new track light and follow the instructions that come with it to wire it up. Ask a new question (with pics) if you run into any issues with the wiring or box installation.

You could, if desired, add additional recessed lights in the corners if you'd prefer that look, instead of the track lights. However, it seems that track lights are coming back into fashion. (A bad call, if you ask me, but that's my opinion and decorating advice is off-topic here...)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, yes.  The cable to the last can light in the line should terminate in a little box that's placed above the ceiling.  You should be able to wire nut another cable into that box and run it to your track lighting.